Who knows the Germany Patent communication methods
anyone knows how Germany Patent Office contact with Patent applicants normally? I DID find some patent office still use ordinary mail to contact with applicants.
I appreciate if someone use their DPMA system share their experience, will they send internal email to your DPMA box? or all the communication will be done by traditional ordinary mail instead of email?
Thanks if you could help or share your experience.

Are you still claiming  to be domiciled in a EU country so you can avoid using a proper practitioner as you were planning in a previous post? Otherwise your agent will handle this for you.

Hi George, this post has nothing to do with domicile, I just want to know the patent office communication ways with the applicant, I fixed the problem of domicile already, thank you for clarification
